# optimus dilemma

Tags: nvidia-optimus

I plan to buy a customized laptop in a week. My main OS on the system would the latest version of ubuntu. Almost all the laptops I am interested in, seem to come with Nvidia optimus and I am well aware that optimus and ubuntu don't play nice with each other.

I would simply like to know what can I expect if I get a customized laptop with nvidia optimus and install ubuntu on it.

1. Would I be able to use the Intel Graphcis Card for most of my work and switch to the card only when I need to?
2. Would I be able to switch off the Nvidia card when I don't need it, to save on power?
3. Would I be better off installing ubuntu 12.04 and bumblebee or ubuntu 12.10 and PRIME?
4. And finally, should I even bother buying a laptop with optimus?

Comment: I bought an Optimus notebook in 2013 and I stopped using Linux after that. Optimus support is very bugged till now. I tryed everything: bumblee, nvidia-prime, Ubuntu, Debian, OpenSUSE... absolutely nothing works as it should, no matter how much I tryed. And I really tryed, I put a lot of effort into making my Optimus notebook compatible with Linux. I'm a long term Linux user, I've been using linux for the past 15 years, most of the time as a Debian user. I tryed every solution there is out there, but nothing works. It kills me not being able to use Linux anymore. Don't buy an Optimus notebook.